Are there any canonical English translations of original analytic EM Hindu authors?
I'm centrally looking for translations of analytic [ Nyaya / Vaiśeṣika ] texts that contain analysis of motion, as described here. I've found the English version of the Prasasastapada that's on the Internet Archive, but it's almost all commentary by word count. From my experiences trying to find uncommented translations of Mèngzi, I sense that this is going to be a persistent problem in finding translated Nyaya / Vaiśeṣika texts in general. Does anyone have good recommendations for places to look?
[I already know to check Anna's Archive and Libgen].

You may have a look at "Matthew Dasti, Stephen Phillips: The Nyaya-sutra: selections with early commentaries. Hacket Publishing Company (2017)". The book has suggestions for further readings. - A general introduction is "Jornardon Ganeri: Philosophy in Classical India. Motilal Banarsidass (2009)". The book has references to original works and their translations. - See also the online bibliogpraphy http://faculty.washington.edu/kpotter/ - I have never read about "the analysis of motion" as a theme in Nyaya-sutra. Can you give me a reference to the corresponding sutras?

I have a hardcopy of the Bhasa Pariccheda with Siddhanta-Muktavali by Isvanatha-Nyaya-Pancanana with translation by Swami Madhavananda (2010 reprint) in Sanskrit and English. ISBN 978-81-7505-112-6. published by www.advaitaasshrama.org Not sure if still available or new reprints now.
